# Zlib usage - deflateEnd() error

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, zlib, memory-management

i am trying to compress block of strings in `partial_flush` mode, moreover there is one case when there is only one string to process.

Now i am calling `deflateInit2(params...)`, `deflate()` and `deflateEnd()`. I get some correct output in output, witch is `uncompressable(tried)`, but there is an error when trying to deallocate all memory using `deflateEnd(&strm);` or `inflateEnd(&strm);`

For now, i am thinking here will be no possibility to create this case on application run, but i need to pinpoint and eliminate error with memory leak.

whole schematis is like this:

```
class Czlib{
    compress( std::string );
    decompress( std::string );
    Czlib() // allocate inflate and deflate state here
   ~Czlib()// deallocate both here
}

int main(){
    for (char c=0x00 ; ; c++){
        std::string str(255, c);
        Czlib zlib;
        zlib.compress(str);
}
```

I know that class should die after each loop and probably it is, but `deflateEnd` and `inflateEnd` keeps reporting `Z_DATA_ERROR`, so in the end dynamically allocated data stays in memory :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`deflateEnd()` returning `Z_DATA_ERROR` means that the deflate operations were left in some intermediate state, i.e. not completed, at the time of that call.  So `deflate()` had never returned a `Z_STREAM_END`.

Regardless, all of the allocated memory for deflate is released by `deflateEnd()`.  So if you're calling `deflateEnd()`, there will be no memory leak for memory allocated by zlib.

To properly complete the deflate stream, you need to give `deflate()` the `Z_FINISH` flush parameter, and then call `deflate()` to consume its output until it returns `Z_STREAM_END`.

Comment: From what i've tried, there is no problem with returning Z_DATA_ERROR or `Z_STREAM_ERROR` by either `inflateEnd()` or `deflateEnd()`, as you said, its just info about not finished state of internal zlib algorithm, however:

in my case i know that:
- ...with `Z_PARTIAL_FLUSH`, every portion(string) will be processed and flushed out...
- ...there is enough memory for output... 
- ...and all input will be consumed.

So there is no problem with `*End()` funciotns calling `Z_*_ERROR`, it will be for sure properly deallocated, even if error is reported.
thank you for help @Mark

Comment: `Z_STREAM_ERROR` is a bigger problem.  That means that the state was either not initialized in the first place, or it was corrupted somehow.  If `deflateEnd()` returns `Z_STREAM_ERROR`, then the allocated memory is _not_ released, since a corrupted `z_stream` structure cannot be trusted to have valid pointers to the allocated memory.  If it returns `Z_OK` or `Z_DATA_ERROR`, then the memory _is_ released.